# K&R Profile not included in built in Profiles on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, profile

For some odd reason, the K&R profile isn't built into my installed version of Eclipse. Does anybody have any suggestions on how to resolve this? I haven't been able to find the import file online either...

Comment: What is the 'K&R profile'? As a long term Eclipse user this means nothing to me so you need to explain this more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using eclipse 4.5 and CDT 8.7.0.201506070905 version I am getting K&R [built-in] profile. Kindly let me know which eclipse CDT version are you using?
and where you downloaded it.

I also exported this profile for you. You can import it in the same preference page.

Download this [K&R [built-in].xml](http://pastebin.com/We21ALsC).